# getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) when using ffmpeg and specifing start time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

This is my code

> ffmpeg -hide_banner -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -y -i palette.png -filter_complex "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" -t 15 output.gif

If I set -ss to 0 or omit it completly then conversion works, but it fails as soon as I specify any value. Video in question is 1 minute long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `ss` before `video.mp4`. Currently it is interpreted as an input option that applies to the PNG file.